# I am trying to use proof of sequence correctly to make valid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Here I am trying to use a proof sequence so that the argument is valid (hint: the last A’ has to be inferred).

(A → C) ∧ (C → B') ∧ B → A'

Here are my steps I tried but not sure if this is correct

1. A → C = Conjunctive Simplification
2. C → B' = Conjunctive Simplification
3. A → B' = Chain Rule
4. B = Conjunctive Simplification
5. A' = Contrapositive

Comment: Step 2 is not justifiable.  ... unless you have a typo in the original sequence.

Comment: oh sorry there is a typo hold on

Comment: there i fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps would be valid if you are trying to prove: $(A\to C)\wedge (C\to B')\wedge B\;\to\; A'$

$$\begin{array}{l|lrc}
0 & (A\to C)\wedge (C\to B')\wedge B & \text{Assumption}
\\[1ex]
1 & (A \to C) & 0, \text{ Conjunctive Simplification} & P\wedge Q\vdash P
\\ && \text{aka Conjunction Elimination}
\\[1ex]
2 & (C \to B') & 0, \text{ Conjunctive Simplification}
\\[1ex]
3 & (A \to B') & 1,2, \text{ Hypothetical Syllogism} & P\to Q, Q\to R\vdash P\to R
\\ && \text{aka the Chain Argument}
\\[1ex]
4 & B & 0, \text{ Conjunctive Simplification}
\\[1ex]
4a & B'' & 4, \text{ Double Negation} & P\vdash P''
\\[1ex]
5 & A' & 3, 4a, \text{ Modus Tollens} & P\to Q, Q'\vdash P'
\\[1ex] \hline
\therefore & \Big((A\to C)\wedge (C\to B')\wedge B\Big)\;\to\; A' & \Box
\end{array}$$

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to prove with $(A\to C)\wedge (C\to B')\wedge B\;\to\; A'$ . But Hypothetical Sylogism? do you mean Disjunctive Syllogism?

Comment: I just never heard of Hypothetical Sylogism

Comment: @rightnight [Hypothetical Syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) is the classical name for the *transitivity of implication* (a.k.a. the chain rule). $${P\to Q \quad Q\to R \over P\to R}\mathrm{HS}$$

Comment: hmmm, okay then